# Как правильно сверстать эти элементы?

Tags: html, css

Дали макет на верстку, но у меня возник вопрос по верстке некоторых мелких элементов, а именно звездочек, которые расположены по всему макету. Проблема в том, что они не являются частью одного фонового изображения, а являются отдельным слоем и как их правильно вписать их в верстку? Просто объединить в одну группу слоев? Но правильно ли это? Я некоторые выделил красным, чтобы было ясно о чем я
**PS Я не прошу сверстать за меня, я лишь прошу совета**

Ссылка на сам макет
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rRRuIVAbT5nb_eHzQsxoeOhV8UaxqR5B/view?usp=sharing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте определить эти объекты привязаны к другим элементам на странице или нет? Какая задумка дизайнера - объекты рандомные, плавают при прокрутке или четко должны располагаться "как-есть".